# When does the game auto-save in Ironman mode?

Tags: xcom-enemy-unknown

Sometimes, if I force quit and reload, I can get lucky and undo an unfortunate misclick. Other times, I'm stuck with the outcome that happened the first time.

When exactly does the game save during Ironman?

Comment: Even attempting to answer this question feels dirty.

Comment: To be honest, I've mostly reloaded because I clicked the top of a structure to place a soldier but the game bugged out and flickered to the bottom floor right as I clicked.

Comment: @Shykin Yeah...I only do this when the game screws up too...

Comment: I am finding the UI pretty flakey on the PC when it comes to moving over/onto significantly different Y-levels.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The game automatically saves at the end of the enemy turn, before you get your first action. If you don't like the way the turn is playing out, you can force quit the game and re-load from the beginning of your turn.

Answer (score 0):

I keep reading over and over that XCom is preserving the random seed on reloads.  This means if you re-load a turn and repeat the exact same actions you'll get the exact same outcome.  You can "game" that by making different decisions.  Are you sure you are repeating the same actions when you get different outcomes?  "Misclick" could mean a lot of things.

Ironman isn't different as far as I can tell.  I was also told the game auto-saved when a new turn started (though this save is not preserved on a "normal" quit).